# Virtual server settings on my Belkin router refuse to save?

Tags: port-forwarding

I need to set up port forwarding on my router. I'm doing this so I can host a small multiplayer Minecraft server, but I'll still need to be able to do this for a variety of other applications in the future, and I'm running into some problems.

I'm following the directions on [this page](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Belkin/F5D7230-4/Minecraft_Server.htm), and everything works fine right up until the last step. On the Virtual Servers page, I type in the ports and IP address and all the information listed, but when I hit Apply Changes, it completely clears the list, and testing whether the port is open confirms that nothing changed. Is there some way I can fix this behavior?

Comment: Does it provide you with any errors messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the routers firmware

Comment: That did it. Not sure why I didn't think to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* use Internet Explorer to save the changes to a Belkin router’s settings; other browsers are not supported.